# bomb lab phase_3, don't know how to find the starting address for switch block

Tags: c, assembly, x86, gdb, disassembly

I am taking this software security class, but I have never done c before, I have taken some computer organization class, but not confident in assembly at all. I commented all the lines in the file generated by `objdump` to help myself understand it, but several things still don't make sense to me.

What I got from gdb is at the end, based on that, can someone explain to me:

1. based on my understanding by now, the string format should be `%d %d`, the number of arguments converted by `sscanf` should be larger than 1, the first argument should be smaller than 5, so I typed `2 3`, but the arrow in `disas` by gdb shows I am still stuck in the first line of the code, I don't know where I am wrong that I just cannot proceed.
2. which line is telling me the rule to switch? I read other people's assembly code, the pattern is like, for example, `*0x402470(,%rax,8)`, the pattern is `0x402470 + %rax*8`, then you can print out the content in the corresponding address, I don't know where to find this pattern. All I can see is that `*%rax`, but when I print it out, it's just the string I typed in.
3. what are `# 0x555555556cf5` in line `<+28>` and `# 0x555555556a80` in line `<+58>`? I found they are always very useful because I read other people's post, I know what I am looking for, but I don't know what they are..
4. I learned `%rax` and `(%rax)`, but what is `*%rax`? I can't imagine there is the case beyond just using the value directly or using the value as an address.
5. based on what I read from gdb tutorial, `x` is to display memory content, and `p` is to print a value, but value is always stored in somewhere of memory, so if I am using an address, are they two just same? when should I use which one?

Any suggestion or guide would be very appreciated!!! I am taking an online class on ARM assembly too, suggestions on what more specific material I should look into would be very appreciated too, thank you!!!!

```
That's number 2.  Keep going!
2 3

Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555552cd in phase_3 ()
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function phase_3:
=> 0x00005555555552cd <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x00005555555552d1 <+4>:     mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00005555555552da <+13>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x00005555555552df <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00005555555552e1 <+20>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
   0x00005555555552e6 <+25>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
   0x00005555555552e9 <+28>:    lea    0x1a05(%rip),%rsi        # 0x555555556cf5
   0x00005555555552f0 <+35>:    callq  0x555555554f20 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
   0x00005555555552f5 <+40>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
   0x00005555555552f8 <+43>:    jle    0x555555555317 <phase_3+74>
   0x00005555555552fa <+45>:    cmpl   $0x7,(%rsp)
   0x00005555555552fe <+49>:    ja     0x55555555539d <phase_3+208>
   0x0000555555555304 <+55>:    mov    (%rsp),%eax
   0x0000555555555307 <+58>:    lea    0x1772(%rip),%rdx        # 0x555555556a80
   0x000055555555530e <+65>:    movslq (%rdx,%rax,4),%rax
   0x0000555555555312 <+69>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x0000555555555315 <+72>:    jmpq   *%rax
   0x0000555555555317 <+74>:    callq  0x5555555559d3 <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555531c <+79>:    jmp    0x5555555552fa <phase_3+45>
   0x000055555555531e <+81>:    mov    $0x2ad,%eax
   0x0000555555555323 <+86>:    jmp    0x55555555532a <phase_3+93>
   0x0000555555555325 <+88>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555532a <+93>:    sub    $0x228,%eax
   0x000055555555532f <+98>:    add    $0x29e,%eax
   0x0000555555555334 <+103>:   sub    $0xee,%eax
   0x0000555555555339 <+108>:   add    $0xee,%eax
   0x000055555555533e <+113>:   sub    $0xee,%eax
   0x0000555555555343 <+118>:   add    $0xee,%eax
   0x0000555555555348 <+123>:   sub    $0xee,%eax
   0x000055555555534d <+128>:   cmpl   $0x5,(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555351 <+132>:   jg     0x555555555359 <phase_3+140>
   0x0000555555555353 <+134>:   cmp    %eax,0x4(%rsp)
   0x0000555555555357 <+138>:   je     0x55555555535e <phase_3+145>
   0x0000555555555359 <+140>:   callq  0x5555555559d3 <explode_bomb>
   0x000055555555535e <+145>:   mov    0x8(%rsp),%rax
   0x0000555555555363 <+150>:   xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x000055555555536c <+159>:   jne    0x5555555553a9 <phase_3+220>
   0x000055555555536e <+161>:   add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000555555555372 <+165>:   retq
   0x0000555555555373 <+166>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555378 <+171>:   jmp    0x55555555532f <phase_3+98>
   0x000055555555537a <+173>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555537f <+178>:   jmp    0x555555555334 <phase_3+103>
   0x0000555555555381 <+180>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000555555555386 <+185>:   jmp    0x555555555339 <phase_3+108>
   0x0000555555555388 <+187>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555538d <+192>:   jmp    0x55555555533e <phase_3+113>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
Quit
(gdb) i r
rax            0x555555758760   93824994346848
rbx            0x0      0
rcx            0x5      5
rdx            0x555555758760   93824994346848
rsi            0x3      3
rdi            0x555555758760   93824994346848
rbp            0x0      0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffdf78   0x7fffffffdf78
r8             0x7ffff7ff7006   140737354100742
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x5      5
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x555555554fe0   93824992235488
r13            0x7fffffffe060   140737488347232
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x5555555552cd   0x5555555552cd <phase_3>
eflags         0x206    [ PF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
(gdb) x/s $rdx
0x555555758760 <input_strings+160>:     "2 3"
(gdb) x/s 0x555555556cf5
0x555555556cf5: "%d %d"
(gdb) x/s $rsp
0x7fffffffdf78: "\206QUUUU"
(gdb) x 0x555555556a80
0x555555556a80: 0xffffe89e
(gdb) p 0x555555556a80
$1 = 93824992242304
(gdb) x/8a 0x555555556a80
0x555555556a80: 0xffffe8a5ffffe89e      0xffffe8faffffe8f3
0x555555556a90: 0xffffe908ffffe901      0xffffe916ffffe90f
0x555555556aa0 <array.3415>:    0xa00000002     0x100000006
0x555555556ab0 <array.3415+16>: 0x100000000c    0x300000009
(gdb) x/s $r8
0x7ffff7ff7006: "8 16 32\no give Tina Fey more material.\n"
(gdb) x/s $r12
0x555555554fe0 <_start>:        "1\355I\211\321^H\211\342H\203\344\360PTL\215\005\252\030"
(gdb) x/s $r13
0x7fffffffe060: "\001"
(gdb) x/s $rip
0x5555555552cd <phase_3>:       "H\203\354\030dH\213\004%("
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You put a breakpoint at that location. To proceed use `stepi`/`nexti` or set another breakpoint. Note that the call is to `sscanf` which uses a string source. Your input has already been read from stdin by that point, it's passed as argument into this function.
2. +65 to +72 is the switch, it's just broken up into parts due to an extra addition.
3. Friendly service of your disassembler. It shows the actual calculated address so you don't have to figure out what e.g. `0x1a05(%rip)` will be.
4. `*` means indirect jump in at&t syntax. `jmp *%rax` is "jump to the address stored in rax". It's needed to differentiate `jmp foo` and `jmp *foo`. Register operands are unambiguous but the notation is still used (`gas` will issue a warning otherwise).
5. Not all values are in memory. To print a register for example you must use `p`. You can use `p` to print content of memory too by dereferencing but `x` is more flexible for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you Jester! Your answer helped me a lot! phase3 is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the binary in a disassembler like Binary Ninja or IDA pro, it will show you the addresses of the switch statements.